# rails array using group + each

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

**Question:** How can I make a grouped array like this?

```
event_id: 1, person_id: 1, tasks: [1, 2] 
event_id: 1, person_id: 2, tasks: [3] 
event_id: 2, person_id: 1, tasks: [4]
```

**The givens:**

Tasks table:

[image]

Event.rb:

```
has_many :tasks
has_many :people
```

Task.rb

```
belongs_to :event
```

Person.rb

```
belongs_to :event
```

My thoughts are to do something like this (doesn't work):

```
- @grouped_tasks = Task.all.group(:event_id, :person_id).each do |z|
  = z.event.id
  = z.member.id
  = z.tasks.collect{|r| r.task.name}.join(",")
  = z.tasks.pluck(:name)
```

Comment: What exactly you want is unclear. You want an array or a table or what? Just write down what you want as final product for 2 3 tasks. I think it is not complicated.

Comment: I'd use an [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) or an [`has_many :through`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) association. You find out which to pick [here](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many).

Comment: @ARK - I want a table grouped like `event_id: 1, person_id: 1, tasks: [1, 2]`

Comment: @3limin4t0r - how would that help?

Comment: @Yshmarov I guess I understood the question wrong. I thought you wanted to save an array as model attribute, but this is about displaying them.

Comment: Please replace the "task table" with a Ruby object that readers can cut-and-paste to test code. Same with the array of hashes: `arr = [{ event_id: 1, person_id: 1, tasks: [1, 2]}, {...}, {...}]`. Notice that I assigned a variable (`arr`) to that array. That way readers can refer to that variable in answers and comments without having to define it. Please also assign a variable to the task table object. In general, do not use pictures of code or data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using an SQL "GROUP BY" with [`group(:event_id, :person_id)`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-group) you could instead group the results using Ruby with [`group_by`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-group_by). This way you've each individual record for each group.

```haml
- task_groups = Task.all.group_by { |task| [task.event_id, task.person_id] }
- task_groups.each do |(event_id, person_id), tasks|
  = event_id
  = person_id
  = tasks.pluck(:id).join(', ')
  = tasks.pluck(:name).join(', ')
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using postgres, you can get the result using following query.

```
Task.all.group(:event_id, :person_id).select("event_id,person_id,array_agg(id) as tasks")
```

Comment: Yes, using postgres

Comment: Then you can achieve the result using this query.